# Avoid matching regex to beginning of line

Tags: python, regex

I have come up with the following regex:

`(.*\\\\documentclass.*)|(.*\\\\documentstyle.*)`

This regex will be used to determine whether a document contains a \documentclass or a \documentstyle tag.

I would like to avoid matching  a string starting with `%` such as this:

`% To use with LaTeX, use \documentstyle[psfig,...]{...}`

How may I include a negative lookbehind of some sort to avoid matching to this string?

Comment: Will matches, if there is one, always start at the beginning of a line?

Comment: Yes always start at beginning of line. Match if there is a \documentclass or \documentstyle and anything else except a % at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anchor to the start of the line with `^` (with multiline mode), negative lookahead for `%`, and then alternate:

```
(?m)^(?!%)(?:.*\\document(?:class|style).*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/WjCkfb/1

Comment: what does this sign mean?  `(?m)`

Comment: That enables multiline mode (it makes the `^` match the start of a line, rather than only the start of the string).